# Jersey 1.18.1 is unable to pick my restful service when deployed on Jboss 7.1.1 final

Tags: rest, jboss, jersey-1.0

I have a very confusing problem with me. I have a eclipse Restful service project which is being built by gradle. I can successfully build and run my application in Tomcat 7.0.54, from within Eclipse and by deploying the war directly in /webapps folder of Tomcat.

But when I deploy my same war in Jboss 7.1.1 Final, it gives me below error.

```
10:43:45,390 WARN  [org.jboss.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011204: resteasy.scan found and ignored in web.xml. This is not necessary, as Resteasy will use the container integration in the JAX-RS 1.1 specification in section 2.3.2
10:43:45,390 WARN  [org.jboss.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011204: resteasy.scan.providers found and ignored in web.xml. This is not necessary, as Resteasy will use the container integration in the JAX-RS 1.1 specification in section 2.3.2
10:43:45,391 WARN  [org.jboss.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011204: resteasy.scan.resources found and ignored in web.xml. This is not necessary, as Resteasy will use the container integration in the JAX-RS 1.1 specification in section 2.3.2
10:43:46,128 INFO  [com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig] (MSC service thread 1-2) Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.impl
  org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs
10:43:46,534 INFO  [com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl] (MSC service thread 1-2) Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: ${project.version} ${buildNumber}'
10:43:47,372 SEVERE [com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules] (MSC service thread 1-2) The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
10:43:47,373 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/xxxxxx]] (MSC service thread 1-2) StandardWrapper.Throwable: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) [jersey-core-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491) [jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321) [jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) [jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) [jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376) [jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559) [jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]

10:43:47,388 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/taxation]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Servlet /xxxxxxx threw load() exception: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) [jersey-core-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790) [jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491) [jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321) [jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) [jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) [jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376) [jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559) [jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
```

Moreover, when I unpack this war to a folder and deploy that folder inside Jboss, it works! It also works if I run my project in Jboss directly from Eclipse. However, if I export the project as a war (from eclipse) and deploy that war file into Jboss, it again gives me same problem.

When I drilled down into the the code of Jersey, I found that `com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner` is not able to pick my class files from the war.

Please help us resolve this issue.

Comment: We downvote a question which does not confirm to 1. Stackoverflow's standards, 2. Answered already by some other question and several others

Comment: Targeting is not a professional way.Just I told you to follow stackoverflow standards :)

Comment: I hug you.we should stop fighting.:)

Comment: Cool. Now remove your downvotes from my questions, if you don't have any specific issue with them, else post the problems.

Comment: I cant do it..Please ask the person who downvoted.I did not downvote..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, and would like to post it so someone else could benefit. The problem was there in our build script. We were using different version of Jersey libraries. For some of the libraries, version 1.18.1 was being used, while for some other version 1.18 was being used.

Once the version for all the libraries was updated to 1.18.1, it worked perfectly.