# JBoss 7 - The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jboss, jersey

I'm having some problems publishing a project .ear in the JBoss 7.1, It works with WAS and publishing directly trough the Eclipse to JBoss, but when publishing trough the .ear in the deployment folder or trough the console in JBoss I have the error "The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.".

I already tried several solutions for this problem, but without success. I found the is possible to solve it, but do not know how.

[Jersey 1.18.1 is unable to pick my restful service when deployed on Jboss 7.1.1 final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445495/jersey-1-18-1-is-unable-to-pick-my-restful-service-when-deployed-on-jboss-7-1-1/32882785?noredirect=1#comment53604173_32882785)

Can someone explain to me the steps to correct this error?

This is my servlet definition in the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.xxxxx.webservices.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Note: When i comment the  tag it works, reading all classes in the project, but that is not acceptable for me, i need to read only in the "com.xxxxx.webservices.rest"

This is my error:

```
12:24:24,562 INFO [com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig] (MSC service thread 1-4) Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages: com.xxxxx.webservices.rest 12:24:24,656 INFO [com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18 11/22/2013 01:21 AM' 12:24:24,672 INFO [stdout] (Thread-68) 

12:24:24,673 INFO [stdout] (Thread-68) No logging specified yet. Temporarily logging to webserver default file.

12:24:24,674 INFO [stdout] (Thread-68) [com.transactionservice.config.ConfigLoader - ] - filePath --> C:/jBoss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/xxxxx/xxxxx/config.properties

12:24:24,675 INFO [stdout] (Thread-68) 

12:24:24,682 INFO [stdout] (Thread-68) 

12:24:24,683 INFO [stdout] (Thread-68) No logging specified yet. Temporarily logging to webserver default file.

12:24:24,684 INFO [stdout] (Thread-68) [com.transactionservice.config.ConfigLoader - ] - filePath --> C:/jBoss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/xxxxx/xxxxx/config.properties

12:24:24,685 INFO [stdout] (Thread-68) 

12:24:24,868 SEVERE [com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules] (MSC service thread 1-4) The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes. 12:24:24,870 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/xxxxx]] (MSC service thread 1-4) StandardWrapper.Throwable: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes. at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.(RootResourceUriRules.java:99) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) [jersey-core-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18] at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]

12:24:24,894 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/xxxxx]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Servlet /xxxxx threw load() exception: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes. at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.(RootResourceUriRules.java:99) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) [jersey-core-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18] at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
```

Comment: you're missing something here  "When i comment the it works"

Comment: When i comment the <init-param> tag it works, but I need to limit only to the com.xxxxx.webservices.rest package.